# No emulator images (avds) found. while running cordova applicaction

Tags: android, cordova, avd-manager

While running my `cordova` application through command promt I'm getting  the following error:

> No emulator images (avds) found.
>   1. Download desired System Image by running:   "D:\Software\sdk\tools\android.bat"sdk
>    2. Create an AVD by running: "D:\Software\sdk\tools\android.bat" avd  HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the
>   HAXM   device driver

How can I fix this issue?

I'm new to this hybrid application development ,please help me out this issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below from your command line:

```
# create avd
android avd

# run emulator
ionic emulate android
```

Comment: I have tried to create emulator on android studio and its working, thanks for you to answer my question, if the question was useful to others kindly upvote my question

Answer (score 0):

I haven't work with cordova applications before, but I think the answer is clear, it's asking you to make an emulator so that your application can run on.
first, you need to run the .bat file specified on your local machine

*D:\Software\sdk\tools\android.bat*

choose the sdk. And then re-run the .bat file choosing avd.

and by doing so an emulator should be installed on your machine for the cordova application to run on.